# Neo4J Causal Cluster using 3 AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j, ec2-ami

We are trying to setup Neo4j Causal Clustering using 3 EC2 instances that we have created in our AWS Account each with Neo4j Enterprise Causal Cluster AMI. We made necessary configurations in the neo4j.template of each Neo4j EC2 Instance to enable Causal Clustering. For example the parameters - causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members and causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address are set to the Public IPs of the EC2.

After making the necessary changes, the Neo4j Server was started using the command ./etc/init.d/neo4j start. When checked the status using systemctl status neo4j, it is still showing neo4j_mode as SINGLE though it was set to CORE. The Neo4j UI is also not accessible from the browser window.

How can we enable Neo4j Causal Clustering using 3 EC2 Instances with Neo4j AMIs.? Is there any specific AMI that we should use with EC2 to enable Causal Clustering.? Is there any documentation for the same (EC2 Neo4j Causal Clustering)? What should be the correct neo4j.conf file configuration for enabling Causal Cluster?